# How to align columns with awk

Tags: awk

I tried to execute below command:

```
ls -ltr | awk 'BEGIN { print "File\t\t\tOwner"} { print $9,"\t",$3} END {print "-DONE \n"}'
```

and getting following o/p

```
File                    Owner

inventory-shipped        root
BBB_list         root
marks    root
test_file        root
awkvars.out      root
1        root
t12      root
-DONE
```

How i can get o/p like

```
File                    Owner

inventory-shipped       root
BBB_list                root
marks                   root
test_file               root
awkvars.out             root
1                       root
t12                     root
-DONE
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: pipe the output to `column -t` for alignment ... but as mentioned beware of parsing ls

Answer (score 5):

You need to use padding except for the last column. Since you have only 2 columns, the first will be enough.

When you use `printf` instead of `print`, you can print all the variables based on a template. The following examples print a string (`%s`) with a padding (`24`) on the right side (`-24`), so it becomes `%-24s`.

```
ls -ltr | awk 'BEGIN {printf "%-24s%s","File","Owner"} { printf "%-24s%s\n",$9,$3} END {print "-DONE \n"}'
```

For more information you can check [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) or [this](https://www.linuxnix.com/awk-scripting-8-awk-printf-statements-examples/).